# Disable ligatures in Xamarin Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, fonts, ligature

I am looking for a way to disable font ligatures in Xamarin Forms.

Any advice how to accomplish that?

Regards
Bernd

Comment: Have you tried to change the IDE font? Which font is currently in use?

Comment: Refer this document https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/text/fonts

Comment: I am usccessfully using the custom font (in my case it is TTNorms) but I find no way to disable the ligatures for Xamarin Forms. In my Website I just use a css ( font-variant-ligatures: none;) for that.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find any solution to disable ligatures in the app.
Using styles in the XAML code was a deadend too because *font-variant-ligatures: none* is a unsupported tag here.

I did solve my problem by editing the ttf file and removing the unwanted ligatures.